# classname pass to React component is lost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollupjs, css-modules

I just wrote an App component to render on the page and my react version is 17. The app component looks like this:

### App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';

import styles from './App.module.scss';

type AppProps = {
  templateString: string;
}

const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({
  templateString = ''
}) => {
  return <div className={styles.uiStage}>
    123
  </div>;
};

export default App;
```

### App.module.scss

```scss
.ui-stage {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

and index.ts is the entry file for my project:

### index.ts

```js
const root = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

But when I start the project, the uiStage class on the div is lost, but the ui-stage style can be found in the style tag. And I also find that all the child components can render the classnames correctly.

Below is my rollup config file:

### rollup.config.js

```js
import serve from "rollup-plugin-serve";
import livereload from "rollup-plugin-livereload";
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

const extensions = [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"];

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: "dist/iife/bundle.js",
      format: "iife", // for local dev
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: "dist/esm/bundle.js",
      format: 'esm', // for esm
      sourcemap: true,
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    image(),
    postcss({
      autoModules: true,
      extensions: [".css", ".scss"],
    }),
    nodeResolve({
      extensions,
    }),
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'development' )
    }),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
      extensions
    }),
    serve({
      open: true,
      verbose: true,
      contentBase: ["", "public"],
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3000,
    }),
    livereload({ watch: "dist" }),
  ]
};
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: @AniketPandey The styles is import from css module

Comment: @AniketPandey Maybe it's not the problem, because I use this in other components  , they all worked, only the root component doesn't work

Comment: What does your final html code for this component look like?

Comment: You use camelCase in js `styles.uiStage` but kebab-case in css `.ui-stage` and as far as I know this will not work by default with css-modules. You might need to add an option for `exportLocalsConvention: 'dashes'` to your `rollup.config.js`

Comment: @Martin because I have use typed-scss-module and generate types file for scss module automatically, and only app compoent doesnt work, other components all works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `styles["ui-stage"]`

Comment: Maybe it is not this reason, because I have generate types.d.ts for the scss files, and in addition to this app component, other child components all can render the class names successfully.

Comment: @ChenLee strange! so even the `styles["ui-stage"]` doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work